# Delete Images From WordPress Media Library

Tags: wordpress, image

I am unable to view any of the media library documents in the grid view. I can see them in the normal list view. I am also unable to upload any new media files.  I have noticed that there are some strange no title files which I think are the cause of the issue but i am unable to delete them as there is no edit or delete button next to any of these [screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ykkW.png). My question is is there a way to delete these odd files from the database?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress media files are not actually stored in the database. They are stored under a folder structure in your web root folder.

If you can make an FTP login, you can get rid of the odd media files as follows:

- Make FTP login
- Navigate to the `wp-content/uploads` folder
- Under the uploads folder, you will find folder/s like 2016, 2015 etc. (depending on how old your site is)
- Within each year, you will find monthly folders
- Within each monthly folder, you will find the media files (that you uploaded during that month/year)
- Browse around to find the offending files and delete

Hope this works for you.

Edit: You can also try one of the following plugins:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-media-library/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I am unable to see the no-title images in the uploads folder.

Comment: You can check the Edit: to my original answer above.

Comment: Thanks I have tried to use these to delete them but it doesn't work.

Comment: Any new images that I upload also appear in the same way with the no-title and I cannot see them, edit them or delete them.